# Android: Firebase and Polymorphism in java?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a chat app using Firebase. When it comes to handling different message types (i.e. text message, image message, voice message), inheritance is a good choice. So I have a BaseMessageClass and other sub classes inherited from the base class. The problem comes when I uploaded it on Firebase and want to retrieve it back.

How do I specify correct child class to the datasnapshot if I put all the values in the same node ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to do so, you have to handle family of objects in different way. See  'Visitor' pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/java/1, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: But when retrieving from the Firebase how are we going to know which type the object belongs to ?

Comment: You'd typically use a marker property for that. Either there's a unique property in each specific subclass and you detect its existence, or you have a single top-level property that indicates the type.